# Python Pandas SQL NaN value issues

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to fix the NaN? i actually have data/values from the first query.
The float value always print as NaN from Pandas but the simple SQL query shows the float values properly.

My code is below

```
import pyodbc as conn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

connection = conn.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                          "Server=GOPALPC\SQLSERVER;"
                          "Database=SCADADB;Trusted_Connection=yes")

mycursor: object = connection.cursor()
SQL_Query_01 = mycursor.execute(
    "SELECT TOP 5 [Channel1_PLC_001_Flow],[Channel1_PLC_001_Level],[Channel1_PLC_001_Water] FROM [SCADADB].[dbo].[DataLogDB]")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
    print(x)

SQL_Query_02 = pd.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT TOP 5 [Channel1_PLC_001_Flow],[Channel1_PLC_001_Level],[Channel1_PLC_001_Water] FROM [SCADADB].[dbo].[DataLogDB]",connection)
df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query_02, columns=['FLOW', 'PRESSURE', 'TEMPERATURE'])
print (df)
```

Result of SQL_Query_01

```
    (171.5, 171.5, 171.5)
    (170.25, 170.25, 170.25)
    (169.5, 169.5, 169.5)
    (168.75, 168.75, 168.75)
    (168.0, 168.0, 168.0)
```

Result of SQL_Query_02

```
    FLOW  PRESSURE  TEMPERATURE
    0   NaN       NaN          NaN
    1   NaN       NaN          NaN
    2   NaN       NaN          NaN
    3   NaN       NaN          NaN
    4   NaN       NaN          NaN
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               import mysql.connector
               import pandas as pd

               dbcon = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost',database = 'nifty',user= 'root',password = 'Your_password')

               cursor = dbcon.cursor()
               sql_query = '''SELECT low,high FROM adaniports LIMIT 3'''
               result = cursor.execute(sql_query)
               myresult = cursor.fetchall()
               for i in myresult:
                   print(i)

               sql_query2 = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,dbcon)
               df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query2,columns=['low','high'])
               print(df)
```

The above code works fine for me.

output -

**result of first query**

```
               (770.0, 1050.0)
               (874.0, 990.0)
               (841.0, 914.75)
```

**result of second query**

```
                    low     high
                0  770.0  1050.00
                1  874.0   990.00
                2  841.0   914.75
```

Comment: Thanks. May i know what may be the issues in my code ?

Comment: haven't used "pyodbc" and not able to diagnose the issue in your code.

Comment: @dhananjaysawarkar Then how is this an answer to the question asked?

Comment: @Tomerikoo it's just another way by which he can get the required output.